# GitHub pull request id from commit hash

Tags: git, github, github-api

How can I get GitHub PR id from commit hash? It is possible in git console or GitHub API?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a minute to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 11):

It is definitely possible using GitHub API (V3). To get the PR ID you will need to use the GitHub Search Issues API and first find the PR number and then you can use the PR number to find the PR id. Take note that a pull request will have a Pull Request ID and a separate Issue ID.

For example, suppose you have a commit sha - `7dd1bcf5f2f5eeed34cc2ec63053098fba302b6c`. To find the PR id from this sha you can do the following:

Step 1: Find the PR number using the commit sha: Use the Github search api-
`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=sha:7dd1bcf5f2f5eeed34cc2ec63053098fba302b6c`. From JSON response, the field 'number' represents the PR number (in this case 16) and 'ID' represents the issue ID (not PR ID)

Step 2: Use the PR number and repo details to find the PR ID. From the JSON response received in step 1 we can construct the following - 
`https://api.github.com/repos/lamassu/lamassu-admin/pulls/16`. In the JSON response received, the field 'ID' is the PR ID required.

Comment: So valuable that I just made a script of it: https://gist.github.com/cbosdo/e67fc8044015caeb3392e4999e66fdef

Answer (score 7):

I have spent a decent amount of time investigating it and here are the results. The solution only uses basic Git functionality and doesn't require any GitHub features. The simple sh line to print pull request id:

```bash
git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head' | grep -F -f <(git rev-parse HEAD) | awk -F'/' '{print $3}'
```

In Groovy Jenkinsfile I'm doing following:

```
def gitCommitSHA = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse  HEAD').trim()
def allPRs = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "origin ‘pull/*/head’")
List result = allPRs.split( '\n' ).findAll { it.contains(gitCommitSHA) && it.contains("refs/pull") }
if (result.size() ==1 ){
  def str = result[0]
  def prId = str.substring(str.indexOf("pull")+5,str.lastIndexOf("head")-1)
  echo "Pull request id: ${prId}"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The commit SHA for example is: 7dd1bcf5f2f5eeed34cc2ec63053098fba302b6c

1. Go to the "Pull requests" tab
2. In the filter enter: `is:pr is:closed 7dd1bcf5f2f5eeed34cc2ec63053098fba302b6c`

If the PR is not closed then remove `is:closed`

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/commits/COMMIT_SHA/pulls
```

With github-cli:
`gh api /repos/OWNER/REPO/commits/COMMIT_SHA/pulls | jq -r .[].html_url`